# How to return multiple values from a Promise with ES6?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have a chain of functions.
Along the way, I need to track 2 temporary variables.

```
let key="string"
...
.then(done => {
    localforage.setItem("key",key)
    console.log ("done: "+done) // WORKS
    return done
}).then(done => {
    let carto = localforage.getItem("key")
    return [carto, done]
}).then(([carto, done]) => {
    console.log ("done: "+done) // WORKS
    console.log ("carto: "+carto) // FAILS
```

It looks like the last `return [carto, done]` is executed as soon as it has one of the values (`done`).

If I replace it with `return carto` it waits and carto has the correct typeof.

But with `return [carto, done]`, the console throws:
`carto: [object Promise]`

How to pass multiple variables in a chain without using globals?

EDIT: I use Svelte and it doesn't want await out of async functions.

Comment: `setItem` is async, btw.

Comment: This seems like something that could be made much simpler with the `async/await` syntax, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `Promise.all`, but in a somewhat odd way - pass into it the `done` from the prior `.then` (which is not a Promise, but a plain value), and also pass it the new `carto`, which *actually is* a Promise. It'll resolve to both values once the singular `carto` resolves.

```
})
.then(done => Promise.all([
  localforage.getItem("key"),
  done,
])
.then(([carto, done]) => {
```

But consider using `await` instead, it makes these sorts of things much cleaner.

`setItem` also returns a Promise that you should wait for.

```
const done = whateverPromiseDoneCameFrom;
await localforage.setItem("key",key);
const carto = await localforage.getItem("key");
```

Comment: Really? This is Local Forage, not Local Storage. I thought it was async https://github.com/localForage/localForage#callbacks-vs-promises

Comment: Hm, no, you're right, there's an async `getItem` there as well. I think the Digital Ocean docs are wrong.

Comment: Thanks, but I use Svelte and it doesn't want await out of async functions.

Comment: @phm Make the function async in order to use `await`, of course.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, thank you for your Promise.all solution, it works!
I think I need to rethink all my process and learn about Promise.all :)